# How to update a table which is being used in nested queries?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table and getting the following error message:

> You can't specify target table 'nodeassociation' for update in FROM clause

This is related to updating a table which is being used in nested or inner subqueries.

This is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE nodeassociation 
SET sink_node_id = 11608 
WHERE sink_node_entity = 'WorkflowScheme' 
  AND source_node_id IN (SELECT source_node_id
                         FROM nodeassociation 
                         WHERE SINK_NODE_ENTITY = 'WorkflowScheme' 
                           AND sink_node_id = 11604 
                           AND SOURCE_NODE_ID IN (SELECT source_node_id
                                                  FROM nodeassociation 
                                                  WHERE association_type = 'ProjectCategory' 
                                                    AND sink_node_id = 11400));
```

The inner queries run fine separately.

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create the temporary table from your subselect and then use it in the update.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to do that? I tried to put the clause "as TempTable" at the end of my second inner query, but it didn't work.

Comment: Create temp table:
`create temporary table tmp_tbl_name as select .... ;`

Run update:
`update tbl1 where id in (select id from tmp_tbl_name)`